# In R produce a running count in column based on previous column with numeric values

Tags: r, trading

I am trying to produce a running count in column 8 based on the the 1's and 0's in column 7.

Unfortunately, I keep getting the error "Error in q[k - 1, 8] + q[k, 7] : non-numeric argument to binary operator".

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

```
for(k in 3:nrow(q)){
  if(q[k, 7] > 0){
  q[k, 8] <- (q[k-1, 8] + q[k, 7])
  q[k, 8] <- as.numeric(q[k, 8])
 }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a cumulative sum?  Not knowing what your input data look like...

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    col1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
    col2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
    col3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
    col4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
    col5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
    col6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
    col7 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
  )

df$col8 <- cumsum(df$col7)

print(df)

  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    0    0
2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1    1
3   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    0    1
4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    0    1
5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1    2
6   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that column 7 or 8 isn't being stored as a factor/character? The line q[k - 1, 8] + q[k, 7] would create an error if either column is anything but logical or numeric.

Try is.numeric() and is.logical() to check your columns.